# write developer debug statements to separate log

Tags: errors, debug

Is there a way to write the debugging I do in my code (ex: `error_log("$msg");` to a different log file than the rest of the system-generated logging that gets written to `/wp-content/debug.log`?

I would settle for being able to show only my debugging along with fatal errors and parse errors all in the same file, but setting:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors', ~E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE);
```

does not seem to do the trick.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell [`error_log()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) where to put its output:

```php
error_log( 'my debugging output', 3, '/my/debug/log/location/log.txt' );
```

It might be more convenient to add your own function:

```php
if ( ! function_exists( 'my_debug' ) ) {

  function my_debug( $x = '' ) {
    // Uses print_r() in case $x isn't a string.
    error_log( print_r( $x, 1 ), 3, '/my/debug/log/location/log.txt' );
  }

}

// ... elsewhere

my_debug( $the_variable_i_want_to_check );
```

Comment: Awesome - thanks!! I also added `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` to the beginning of `x` so the date and time are captured and `"\n"` to the end so that each entry is displayed on a new line.